# WordPress slick slider error on staging but not local

Tags: php, wordpress, slider, staging

I have a WordPress site locally and I have used 'Slick Slider' and ACF to create an image gallery in a custom post.

This all works great locally, but when I have pushed to my staging site, the area where the slider should be, is a large blank whitespace. 
I have the following error when I 'inspect' on the background-image of the gallery item:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant sizes - assumed 'sizes' in /home/sitename/uat_capistrano/releases/20190405.../wp-content/themes/.../content-single-experiences.php on line 62.

This is my code for the slider:

```
<div class="slider">
    <?php 
    $images = get_sub_field('trip_gallery');
    $full = 'large';
    $thumb = 'thumbnail';                                
    if( $images ): ?>                                   
        <ul>                                    
            <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>           
                <li class="container"  data-thumb="<?php echo $image[sizes][$thumb]; ?>" style="height: 600px; background-image: url('<?php echo $image[sizes][$full]; ?>');"></li>                 
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>                                    
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

If anyone could shed any light on why this would't work on staging but it works locally, it would be most helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As PHP says, `sizes` isn't a valid variable/constant name: `$image[sizes][$thumb]`.

Assuming `sizes` is an array key, it should be `$image['sizes'][$thumb]` instead:

```
<div class="slider">
    <?php 
    $images = get_sub_field('trip_gallery');
    $full = 'large';
    $thumb = 'thumbnail';                                
    if( $images ): ?>                                   
        <ul>                                    
            <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>           
                <li class="container"  data-thumb="<?php echo $image['sizes'][$thumb]; ?>" style="height: 600px; background-image: url('<?php echo $image['sizes'][$full]; ?>');"></li>                 
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>                                    
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try, but how come it works locally the way I have it?

Comment: @Leanne chances are that: 1. you're using a different PHP version than the one from the staging server, and/or 2. you have `WP_DEBUG` set to `false` on your local environment which would explain why you didn't see this notice before.

Comment: So I changed `[sizes]` to `['sizes']`. This works as it should locally, and the images on staging are now showing, however the images that should be `[$thumb]` are full size instead. My local php is 5.6.36 and my staging is 5.6.40. Would that really make a difference? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Maybe WordPress was unable to find the corresponding size? What does `var_dump($image['sizes'][$thumb])` display? By the way, since the original question was answered you may want to [mark this answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).